# jQuery hide previous class based on current class

Tags: jquery

heres what im trying to do, pertty much i have a dropdown and i want that shows categories(level-0) and the subcategories (level-1).
If there is sub categories, i want to hid the parent. Im using jquery but it is not doing what i need.

Can anyone provide assistance.

```
<ul class="chzn-results">
        <li style="" class="active-result result-selected" id="cat_chzn_o_0">Select category</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_1">Amphibians</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_2">Arthropods</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-1" id="cat_chzn_o_3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Insects</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-1" id="cat_chzn_o_4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Scorpions</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-1" id="cat_chzn_o_5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Spiders</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-1" id="cat_chzn_o_6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Crustaceans</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_7">Birds</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_8">Fish</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_9">Fungi and Lichens</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_10">Mammals</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_11">Mollusks</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_12">Other</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_13">Plants</li>

        <li style="" class="active-result level-0" id="cat_chzn_o_14">Reptiles</li>
    </ul>


jQuery(".chzn-results li.level-1").each(function(index, value) {
    jQuery(this).prevAll().hide();
});
```

Comment: Your question(_if any_) is not clear, can you provide more details? What dropdown are you talking about? The `ul` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zcd5/) , so you just use:

```
jQuery(".chzn-results li.level-1").each(function(index, value) {
    jQuery(this).prevAll('li.level-0').hide();
});
```

This way you just look for the first li.level-0 that you find, not all of them.